# Tensorflow NaN Loss During Regression With Parameters 0

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I've got a dataset of 731 rows * 987 columns, attempting to regress on the first column. Loss is immediately NaN on the very first training step. I don't see how.

I built the model from the tensorflow custom estimators tutorial, so I'm building a structure of layers, giving a model function to an estimator, and calling estimator.train. Since it's a regression, loss is tf.losses.mean_squared_error.

Debugging steps in trying to figure out this immediate NaN loss:

Weight and bias initializers are tf.zeroesinitializer, and learning rate is 0.

With a batch size of 731 (the number of rows) I can run the model with the first 49 columns, including a 50th column makes loss NaN.

With a batch size of 9, I can run it with all columns at about 6000 loss.

With a batch size of 10 and all columns, loss is NaN (on the first step, as always).

Replacing all of my data with 0 allows me to run all the columns and the full batch size.

This suggests to me that the issue is something overflowing, since the number of datapoints included affects NaN-ness. But I've got no idea how to fix it. What could be causing loss to be NaN on the first step when I include too much data initially? As a secondary question, what further debugging steps should I have taken to figure that out?

Comment: What sort of magnitudes are you working with? (For instance, what are the means for each of your columns?) If the issue is simply overflowing, you may find that normalizing your data by column will solve the issue (and may well simplify the work of the optimization routine as well).

Comment: Data ranges from 0.001 to 15000 (in different columns). It's a substantial range, and it would probably help to normalize, but I don't think that it would be overflowing anything.